# Codeception - Webhelper could not be found and loaded

Tags: codeception

I want to configure my selenium webdriver for Codeception. I'm editing the `acceptance.suite.yml` file and I get this error:

Updated:

> Module Web could not be found and loaded

Updated:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - \Helper\Web // Does not work
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
      PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
      WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
            browser: 'chrome'
```

test code:

```
<?php 
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Overview');
?>
```

EDIT: Without `\Helper\Web` it works but in the URL is just written `data:,` and not `localhost`

Comment: Try `\Helper\Acceptance`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late answer, by the way, but now the error comes with -Webhelper. Same error message

Comment: Change it to `\Helper\Web` :) The naming convention has changed in Codeception 2.1.  Look for helper files in tests/_support/Helper/ directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. He does not find that either, but I do not give up! ;-)

Comment: WebHelper is not built-in, have you created a helper with such name?

Comment: I didn't create anything. I've just took the template from the codeception site. So I've just deleted that line \Helper\Web, installed the google webdriver (because that was an error too) and executed the cept file. Selenium starts the website, (that I entered in my settings), but it doesn't call the URL I entered, in the URL is just written "data:," nothing more. So it seems, that I need that \Helper\Web, or?

Comment: What template? Web Helper should only exist if you have a suite named web or if you explicity created such helper.

Comment: Please show your test code too.

Comment: http://codeception.com/11-20-2013/webdriver-tests-with-codeception.html from this site I copied the class "WebGuy" if you scroll down a bit, you'll see it. Yes hang on a secound, I'll update this immediately and btw thanks for helping me

Comment: That article is 3 years old, the naming convention has changed.

Comment: But I changed that in - \Helper\Web ...what should I do then?

Comment: delete that line, you don't have such helper.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out yesterday. I deleted that line and I installed the ChromeDriver. Thanks for hanging up so long with me on this problem.